# Building Selection Criteria to filter record set

Tags: ms-access, vba

I use a series of if-then statements to build a selection criteria to filter records. There are several unbounded combo boxes and now I want to add checkboxes (if they are check to the criteria.) Here is the code that I am having a problem with (doesn't error or give a result - just back record):

This Section Processes checkbox minseries for true

```
If chkMiniSeries = True Then 'checkbox is checked'
SelCrit = SelCrit & xAnd & MiniSeries_TV = True 'add checkbox to SelCrit'
xAnd = " And "
End If
```

The bold indicates where i am looking for help!

Thanks for any support

Comment: I got ab answer that works SelCrit = SelCrit & xAnd & "MiniSeries_TV = -1"

Answer (score 0):

You are building a filter string, so you need to concatenate a string:

```
SelCrit = SelCrit & xAnd & "MiniSeries_TV = True"
```